# How to select a div inside an Handsontable cell editor

Tags: dojo, handsontable, summernote

I am trying to integrate the 3rd party text editor Summernote (http://summernote.org) inside the cell editor of Handsontable (v0.13).

Unfortunately, I can't focus the div that Summernote uses as an input as Handsontable doesn't consider it an input.

After several tests, I'm sure that Handsontable is messing with the click event, but I don't succeed in stopping the propagation of this event inside Handsontable. Any idea would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer for this problem by adding the following code to the Handsontable configuration, which allows not to close my cell Editor on Click inside:

```
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(myGridContainer, 'mousedown', function(event){                  
     //If I click on container of my Text editor or children
     if($(event.target).is('.GridWidgetHTMLLEditor *, .GridWidgetHTMLLEditor')) {
                //The tricky Handsontable propagation stop
                Handsontable.Dom.enableImmediatePropagation(event);
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     }
});
```

I also had to use a little workaround since it wasn't enough (I had an Handsontable handler, that I couldn't prevent). I needed to add the option "fragmentSelection: true" to Handson settings AND append the created cell Editor container inside the main tbody of Handson (1st child tbody from .htContainer)

It's a little hack allowing to state that the summernote div input is an input (Handsontable doesn't define div as an input).

I can add the Handson code that I needed to workaround for more understanding if you ask to!

Since it's working: <("<)(>")><("<)(>")> o/